# time format cannot be matched from csv with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a simple csv file for which I want to calculate the sum for each day of the value.

The file looks like this (my even easier test-csv is further down below):

```
date;value
"28.02.2021 18:49";"500"
"27.02.2021 18:21";"12"
"27.02.2021 14:21";"54"
```

I already found some great answers how to do that, but I cannot get the date string formatted.
This does always give me the error that it doesn't match the format.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('test.csv', names=['date', 'value'], sep=';'))
mytime = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%d.%m.%Y")
```

For the code above I even made a much easier csv like this:

```
date;value
28.02.2021;500
27.02.2021;12
27.02.2021;54
```

But I still get the same error. Any help is highly appreciated before I will eat my own face. Thanks.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    mytime = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%d.%m.%Y")
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 805, in to_datetime
    values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 460, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 424, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    arg, format, exact=exact, errors=errors
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx", line 144, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime
ValueError: time data 'date' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y' (match)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas generally does a good job inferring datetimes automatically. The following worked for me (pandas version 1.1.4).

#### test.csv

```
date;value
"28.02.2021 18:49";"500"
"27.02.2021 18:21";"12"
"27.02.2021 14:21";"54"
```

#### Working Code

```
import pandas as pd
        
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=';')
pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

#### Output

|  | date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-02-28 18:49:00 |
| 1 | 2021-02-27 18:21:00 |
| 2 | 2021-02-27 14:21:00 |

If you want to be explicit about the datetime format, you can use the format string `'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'`.

#### Code

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
```

#### Output

|  | date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-02-28 18:49:00 |
| 1 | 2021-02-27 18:21:00 |
| 2 | 2021-02-27 14:21:00 |

---

## Edit

I tried running the code snippet you provided above and the problem isn't with the datetime conversion, but rather how you read in your csv. `pd.read_csv` by default will infer column names from the first row of the file. However, when you specify the `names` parameter it treats the first row of the file as data, not column names. The result is is the first row of your DataFrame is the column names, not the data.

#### Code

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('test.csv', names=['date', 'value'], sep=';')
df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=';')
```

#### df1

|  | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | date | value |
| 1 | 28.02.2021 18:49 | 500 |
| 2 | 27.02.2021 18:21 | 12 |
| 3 | 27.02.2021 14:21 | 54 |

#### df2

|  | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 28.02.2021 18:49 | 500 |
| 1 | 27.02.2021 18:21 | 12 |
| 2 | 27.02.2021 14:21 | 54 |

Also, `pd.read_csv` returns a DataFrame. No need to explicitly call `pd.DataFrame()`. There are a lot of neat things you can do with `pd.read_csv`, and I highly recommend you check out the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html.

Comment: You should set keyword `dayfirst=true` in this case - otherwise, this is inferred element-wise (and will be wrong for dates like e.g. 4.7.2020).

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm sure I've tried this yesterday with omitting the names of the columns, but it didn't work.. Anyway, tried it again and it works now. Thanks a lot!